# DatePicker doesn't display inactive numbers

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I use the same DatePicker code in three builds and on two numbers are display properly and on the one is a empty space.

ScreenShot : 
[image]

Here is my DatePicker code:

```
                <DatePicker
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:calendarViewShown="false"
                android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Can anyone help my and find the root of the issue? I tried to changed text color in xml but it didn't work.

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: Let's see above screen. Date outside of selection bar is not displayed.

Comment: Remove android:calendarViewShown="false"
                android:datePickerMode="spinner" lines of code 
Follow https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/default-datepickerdialog/

Comment: Spinner is shown anyway for api < 21 so switching to calendar doesn't solve my problem. In project min api level is 19.

Answer (score 1):

You can  use below code to use DatePicker.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DatePicket"
    android:id="@+id/btn_datePicker"/> place this in xml file.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
   {
   btn_datePicker=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_datePicker);
   btn_datePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
    @Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn_datePicker:
            DatePicker.getDatePicker(this);
            break;
       }
     }
  } 

  Create a class called as DatePicker.

  public class DatePicker
  {
   public static void getDatePicker(Activity c)
   {
    int year,month,day;
    Calendar calendar;
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dd = new DatePickerDialog(c, new        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    dd.show();
}
```

Comment: I use this code and it doesn't work in this case. Values in a spinner still disappear after scrolling.